# Enterprise Architect - Executable State Machine - Time based transitions

Tags: uml, state-machine, enterprise-architect

It has been a while I'm working with Enterprise Architect 13.5 and simulating state machines.
Until now I manage transitions with simple triggers which are available in the simulation events window.

I am looking for a way to make a time based transition between two states but I do not figure how to do it.

[image]

When simulation is running I can't find a way to manage a 30s timeout between two states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from

https://sparxsystems.com/resources/user-guides/15.1/simulation/executable-state-machines.pdf

at page 8

"Trigger and Events -- An Executable StateMachine supports event handling for Signals only. To use Call, Timing or Change Event types you must define an outside mechanism
to generate signals based on these events."

Answer (score 0):

Well, you already have answered your question. When you open the properties of the transition you see the properties where you can enter something like

[image]

The specification is as simple as that. Once you save that you see the trigger name along the transition:

[image]

Pretty much straight forward, isn't it?

Comment: maybe I misunderstood your question and you are asking something specific with the simulation?

Comment: Yes, it is not a matter of specification only.
I wonder if is is possible to specify for the simulation a duration before executing the transition, and actually makes the simulation use this delay.

Comment: You could contact Sparx support or post on Sparx' forum. I don't use the simulator so I can't answer. But some of the Sparx guys are active on their forum and might have an answer.